# Angular 4 routing issue for child routes in nested router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-router

My code is as follows :

> app component html

```
<app-header ></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

> And routing.module.ts is

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginPage, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren : './main.module#MainModule' } // lazy load post login success
];

export const appRouter: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true });
```

> Below is my main.componnt.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-md-2">
            <router-outlet name="nav"></router-outlet>
        </nav>
        <section class="col-md-4">
            <router-outlet name="list"></router-outlet>
        </section>
        <section class="col-md-6">
            <router-outlet name="form"></router-outlet>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Below is main.module.ts

```
const childRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SideNav, outlet: 'nav' }, // working
  { path: '', component: BlankComponent, outlet: 'form' },// working
  { path: '', component: BlankComponent, outlet: 'list' },// working
  { path: 'someform', component: SomeForm, outlet: 'form' },// issue
  { path: 'somelist', component: SomeList,  outlet: 'list' },// issue
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFound, outlet: 'list' },
];

const mainRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainComponent, children: childRoutes }// works
];
export const mainRouter : ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(mainRoutes);
```

I get below error

> **Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'someform'**

Where my router link is 
`[routerLink]="[navObj.url]"`  where url contain `"someform"` or `"./somelist"`

blank path components loading correctly but with path I am facing issue.

is `router-outlet` inside another components router outlet supported in Angular 4?

What is the correct to implement above? I will add `authGuard` later.

Comment: you can use an abstract base class to implement router-outlet in another router-outlet scenario. Provide a router outlet in the abstract class and the make your main component extend the abstract class.

Comment: modified `routerLink` to `[{ outlets: { list: ['somelist'] } }]` but now its not able find `dashboard` route

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make your routes like this :

```
//routing.module.ts 
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginPage, pathMatch: 'full' },
];

//main.module.ts
const childRoutes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: 'dashboard', component: MainComponent , 
        children : [
                        { path: 'newform', component: NewForm, outlet: 'form' },
                        { path: 'testlist', component: TestList, outlet: 'list' }
                    ]
    }
];
```

Comment: moving dashboard to main.module solved by problem for lazy loading.. but named `router-outlet` issue still persistent. I have modified the questing with my new issues.

Comment: @AnupB, please dont change your original question, if you get new issue after solving current one then post new question, this makes no values to our answer, so please revert the question and posr another question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to arrange your routes in separate file for modules. See one of my project directory structure below.

[image]

my sample codes are..

### app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// import { HomeComponent } from './home/index';
// import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
// import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component';
// import { RegisterComponent } from './register/index';

import { AuthGuard, GuestGuard} from './shared/_guards';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AppLayoutComponent } from './_layout/app-layout/app-layout.component';
import { ClientListComponent } from './clients/client-list/client-list.component';

// App routes
const appLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'clients', component: ClientListComponent },
];

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '', 
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: AppLayoutComponent, 
        data: { title: 'App Views' }, 
        children: appLayoutRoutes
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

### auth.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard, GuestGuard } from './../shared/_guards';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from './reset-password/reset-password.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent ,canActivate : [GuestGuard] },
  { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate : [GuestGuard] },
  { path: 'reset/password', component: ResetPasswordComponent, canActivate : [GuestGuard] },
];

export const AuthRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

### auth.module.ts (You can see AuthRoutes imported and added in imports:[ ])

```
import { SharedModule } from './../_shared/shared.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from './reset-password/reset-password.component';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';


import { AuthRoutes } from './auth.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    AuthRoutes
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    LogoutComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

Comment: Have you added multiple `router-outlet` with name? and which are nested inside main router-outlet?